# How to modify or duplicate the Share Screen in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form that I would like my employees to complete each day.  To that end, I added a script to the spreadsheet to auto-email a link to the form to everyone that the spreadsheet is shared with.  There is also a weekly email of their responses sent back.  I have stored all the shared users in a ScriptDb.  What I would like to do is write a UiApp that will allow user preferences to be set so the daily/weekly emails can be disabled.  I would also like to be able to add new users here that do not have the sheet shared with them (for those who just have the link).  My entire company uses google so I don't have to worry about someone not being signed in or having access.

At first I tried creating a simple UiApp form that just showed existing shared users with check boxes for the email preferences.  My doPost was never called, I'm still not sure why.  However, what I would really like would be a screen that looks just like the Share Settings screen but instead of Edit/View access, I would have the user preferences.  Adding users to my custom version of the screen would not add them as collaborators or viewers.

Any ideas on how to re-create the Share screen using UiApp?

If that is not possible, then what am I doing wrong in my current simple preference screen?

```
function editUserPreferences() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

updateUserPreferences();
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var results = db.query({});
var saveUserRow = [];

//define form
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Edit User's Email Preferences");
app.setHeight(550).setWidth(800);
var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm');
var formContent = app.createGrid(results.getSize()+5,3);
formContent.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Email Address'));
formContent.setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel('Receive Daily'));
formContent.setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel('Receive Weekly'));
formContent.setWidget(1, 1, app.createLabel('Reminder'));
formContent.setWidget(1, 2, app.createLabel('Entries'));

var row = 2;  
while (results.hasNext()) {
var obj = results.next();
row = row+1;
formContent.setWidget(row, 0, app.createTextBox().setValue(obj.email).setReadOnly(true));
formContent.setWidget(row, 1, app.createCheckBox().setValue(obj.preferences.dailyEmail).setName('daily' + row));
formContent.setWidget(row, 2, app.createCheckBox().setValue(obj.preferences.weeklyEmail).setName('weekly' + row));
obj.row = row;
saveUserRow.push(obj);
}

// file changes
var results = db.saveBatch(saveUserRow, false);
if (db.allOk(results)) {
// everything went swimmingly, proceed
} 
else {  // partial or no success
for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length; i++) {
var item = results[i];
if ((typeof item.success) == 'function' && !item.success()) {
MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), "Error Updating Script Database", Logger.getLog());
}
}
}

row = row + 2;
formContent.setWidget(row, 1, app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));

form.add(formContent);
app.add(form);
ss.show(app);
}

function doPost(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var results = db.query({});
var editedUserData = [];

Logger.log("in doPost");
while (results.hasNext()) {
var obj = results.next();
var dailyParam = "daily" + obj.row;
var weeklyParam = "weekly" + obj.row;
Logger.log("test");
Logger.log(obj.email);
Logger.log(dailyParam);
Logger.log(weeklyParam);
obj.preferences.dailyEmail = e.parameter.dailyParam;
obj.preferences.weeklyEmail = e.parameter.weeklyParam;
Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(obj));
editedUserData.push(obj);
}

app.close();
return app;
}
```

Nothing is logged from doPost and the last entries in the execution transaction are:

```
FormPanel.getId()
FormPanel.getId()
UiInstance.isStandardsMode()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kmt - there is no way to control the Share screen programmatically. You'll have to rebuild it like you are doing here.

Regarding your issue with doPost - I see it working. I think there is a logger issue where the logs generated in doPost (asynchronously dont work). Try creating a file or appending to a spreadsheet in doPost and that will work.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just created another sheet in my spreadsheet to control access for users.  Thanks!